# OpenCV android ICS

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, android-camera

I extended an OpenCV4Android sample (based on JavaCameraView in 2.4.3.1)  to do some vision processing in my app. The processing works on 2.3.3 and above, except for any 4.x phones. I have looked into the issue, and it seems as though the problem is that the following line is used:

```
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
```

Apparently ICS doesn't like being handed a null surfaceView. The results on 4.x are that the screen appears to be black, and there are no frames passed to onPreviewFrame().

I'd really appreciate any help on this!

The full code is can be found [here](http://fossies.org/dox/OpenCV-2.4.3/android_09JavaCameraView_8java_source.html).

Comment: Don't post single line without surrounding code. The line you've posted is legacy fallback and is never called by OpenCV examples on Android 4.x.

Comment: The reason for the single line was to refer to what I think the problem is. I have updated to refer to the file I'm using - JavaCameraView. There are samples that use that class, and mCamera.setPreviewDisplay is definitely used.

Comment: Just tested sample3 - Native and I get the same results. I'm just asking whether there might be a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I was using 2.4.3.1, which did NOT work on ICS, as I said. I hadn't realised it had been fixed in 2.4.3.2, which just changes the line mentioned in the question to:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
      mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(MAGIC_TEXTURE_ID);
      getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
      mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
  } else
      mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
```

The target needs to be changed to 3.0 to use SurfaceTexture.

You can find more discussion about this problem in [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-opencv/KVqUzyF8e3A/d4F5kZFQzacJ).